# Select all the values from table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have `table(hh_release_eng_20130109$b3009)` and the result is

```
 1    2   3   4 
 76   7  56 160
```

I want to select all the values from that table

```
select.all <- hh_release_eng_20130109 %>%
filter( hh_release_eng_20130109$b3009==1 &  hh_release_eng_20130109$b3009==2 &
        hh_release_eng_20130109$b3009==3 &  hh_release_eng_20130109$b3009==4 )
```

is there any shortcut for this?
many thanks in advance,

Comment: you mean `hh_release_eng_20130109 %>%
  filter(b3009 %in% 1:4)` ?

Comment: @SeymaKalay You need to say `|` instead of `&`.

Comment: Maybe `hh_release_eng_20130109[ !is.na(hh_release_eng_20130109$b3009), ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what your looking for (I'm using `mtcars` as sample data):

```
mtcars[mtcars$carb %in% as.numeric(as.data.frame(table(mtcars$carb))$Var1),]
```